# Contributing multiple separate features to github repository properly via fork

Tags: git, github

I currently contribute to a repository A which I do not own via a fork A-fork of this repository. I understand how I make a pull-request, so that I can encapsulate separate features into different pull-requests. But how is this managed on my local side? I currently have the fork A-fork on github, so I clone it to my machine, make my changes and push it to my fork A-fork, then I pull-request to A. But how can I now contribute another separate feature? If I continue working on the same fork A-fork, I am going to contribute the new feature combined with the old feature, because the commits I make are subsequent. However, I do not intend to delete my fork A-fork and make another (A-another-fork) to contribute something else, because by that I lose my contributed code kept in A-fork.

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can I now contribute another separate feature?

If your new feature does not require the changes you made in a previous pull request, then you can just start working on a new branch based on master:

```
git checkout -b my-next-feature origin/master
```

If your features *do* depend on your existing pull request, then base the new branch on your existing PR:

```
git checkout -b my-next-feature my-first-feature
```

A pull request you make from this branch will initially include all the commits from your *other* pull request, but once that one has merged, you can rebase `my-next-featuer`:

```
git remote update
git rebase origin/master
git push -f
```

Comment: True, of course! I completely forgot about branching.